# AngularJS + JSON + Jackson handle special characters

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, jackson

I need to send a JSON like this, for example

```
{
    "key" : "Title",
    "value" : "TEST & TEST"
}
```

I get parse error becouse of the '&'. I tried to do encodeURIComponent on value before sending the JSON. The value became something like this:

```
"TEST%20%26%20TEST"
```

But I still get the error, probably because '%' is an invalid character too. So how can I handle these characters?.

EDIT:

I get "unexpeted end-of-input in VALUE_STRING", but only when I send & (that becames %26). I have no problem sending %20. What can it be?!

Comment: Must use Jackson? Why isn't `JSON.stringify(jsonObject)` okay in your situation? What is AngularJS related to in your issue?

Comment: Yep I must use Jackson. I dunno if angular is relater, I think not. If I use stringify the & remains & and I get the exception

Comment: You get an exception because you're sending data. Please tell us how you send the JSONed data to the server at the moment. (`$http`?)

Comment: Yep it's $http. I edited the question btw

Comment: Are you sending data by `GET` or `POST` http?

Comment: It's POST. In fact if I delete the & it works well, it's not that I reach the GET limit. The parsing stops exactly at ....:"TEST right there where there's that special char

Comment: What's wrong assuming you use `$http.post("/myEndpoint", JSON.stringify(myJson))` to send data?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong but It doesn't work, I still get the error..

Comment: Please share the code using Jackson for parsing

Comment: I was thinking it was jackson the problem too. But I can't share it, I didn't do it and I don't even know where it is. But as I said it must be a jackson problem, isn't it..?

Comment: Seems like it is. It's sad you don't post it anyway, good luck

Comment: It's sad...I just can't. If the person in charge of the server side development will find the solution I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

using

encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(object_to_be_serialised))